# Generic runtimeType gives _Type instead of the real type

Tags: flutter, dart

We are dealing with a legacy API where the API in some cases will return a different type than expected. So I want to have some extion on a map to retrieve the property or return null.

```
extension Wrapper<T> on Map<String, dynamic> {
  T? property({required String key}) {
    final value = this[key];
    
    if (T.runtimeType == value.runtimeType) {
      return value;
    } 
    return null;
  }
}
```

Using the method:

```
final String? val2 = map.property(key: "bool");
```

The problem is that the T.runtimeType gives _Type instead of String.
How can I get the real property type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because T is already is type by itself. When you call `runtimeType` from `Type` you get a `Type`;

Try use `toString()` method from Type and compare the value.

For your case i did couple changes.
Move generic from `Wrapper<T>` to method property:

```
extension Wrapper on Map<String, dynamic> {
  T? property<T>({required String key}) {
    final value = this[key];

    if (T.toString() == value.runtimeType.toString()) {
      return value as T;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then call it with your type with every property:

```
map.property<int>(key: 'intKey');
map.property<String>(key: 'someString');
```

Next case works fine:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = {'str': 'Some string', 'int': 42, 'array': []};

assert(map.property<int>(key: 'int') == 42); // true
```

Comment: This is much better. That I didn't come up with this myself is a bit stupid :-).

Answer (score 1):

`T` is already a `Type` object, so you can just compare it directly:

```dart
T == value.runtimeType
```

Note that such an equality check tests for *exact* type identity; it will not return true if one type is a subtype of the other.

If you want to check if `value.runtimeType` is a subtype of `T`, then you instead should use simply:

```dart
value is T
```